# Deleting a very big folder in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a very big folder in Google Cloud Storage and I am currently deleting the folder with the following django - python code while using Google App Engine within a 30 seconds default http timeout.

```
def deleteStorageFolder(bucketName, folder):
    from google.cloud import storage
    cloudStorageClient = storage.Client()
    bucket = cloudStorageClient.bucket(bucketName)
    logging.info("Deleting : " + folder)
    try:
        bucket.delete_blobs(blobs=bucket.list_blobs(prefix=folder))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(str(e.message))
```

It is really unbelievable that Google Cloud is expecting the application to request the information for the objects inside the folder one by one and then delete them one by one.

Obviously, this fails due to the timeout. What would be the best strategy here ?

(There should be a way that we delete the parent object in the bucket, it should delete all the associated child objects somewhere in the background and we remove the associated data from our model. Then Google Storage is free to delete the data whenever it wants. Yet, per my understanding, this is not how things are implemented)

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not have folders. The concept of parent/child is emulated in software. You could list the objects in a folder and then spin off threads to delete each object in parallel.

Comment: Yes, Google Cloud Storage have the concept of objects for files and directories. In Google App Engine by design you have a 30 seconds time out for a Django Application. Creating threads to delete each object in parallel will not solve this which will still get into a timeout, but I think I can do this in Google App Engine Flex.

Comment: The namespace for Google Cloud Storage is `FLAT`. Directories do not exist. Everything is an object in the root folder. The HTTP Request timeout for App Engine is 10 minutes, therefore the limitation of 30 seconds is in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 simple options in my mind until the client library supports deleting in batch - see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142641783 :

1. if the GAE image includes the gsutil cli, you could execute `gsutil -m rm ...` in a subprocess
2. my favorite, use `gcsfs` library instead of the G library. It supports batch-deleting by default - see https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/gcsfs/core.html#GCSFileSystem.rm

Comment: Very interesting, I wasn't aware of existence of  "gcsfs", let me have a detailed look. Thanks.

Comment: gcsfs can be dangerous if you have multi-sessions. GCSFS is using session cache.
"GCSFileSystem maintains a per-implied-directory cache of object listings and fulfills all object information and listing requests from cache. This implied, for example, that objects created via other processes will not be visible to the GCSFileSystem until the cache refreshed. Calls to GCSFileSystem.open and calls to GCSFile are not effected by this cache.

In the default case the cache is never expired." [https://readthedocs.org/projects/gcsfs/downloads/pdf/stable/]

Comment: @velizar there is nothing dangerous about it. You misunderstood the reason for the cache. It just means it reads the bucket/folder/path content once and caches the list for future requests. If the content has changed, one can simply flush the cache with `invalidate()`

Comment: `gcsfs` is very fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround. You can do this in 2 steps

1. "Move" your file to delete into another bucket with Transfert
   [image]

Create a transfert from your bucket, with the filters that you want to another bucket (create a temporary one if needed). Check "delete from source after transfer" checkbox
[image]

2. After the successful transfer, delete the temporary bucket. If it's too long, you have another workaround.

   - Go to bucket page
   - Click on lifecycle
     [image]
   - Set up a lifecycle where you delete file with age > 0 day
     [image]

In both cases, you rely on Google Cloud batch feature because by yourselves is too, too, too long!

Comment: Thanks for the amazing emotional rollercoaster walkthrough. Yet,  this needs to be done programatically, for possibly 10K of files in a Google App Engine Django application with a 30 second timeout default restriction as explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: 10k object in 30 secondes could be achieve with an highly parallel language, such as go, because the most of the time, the app waits the API answer. Perform all the delete request in parallel and wait the end is possible. however, the next limit will be the hotspot. According with your file naming, it could highly slow the request in parallel.

Comment: In any case, rethink your use case: delete 10k file in 1 request and less than 30s, synchronously. Are you sure of your design? I recommend you to do things in other way. For example, create a Cloud Task and let the task calling your AppEngine asynchronously and performing the deletion job. With [AppEngine auto scaling, you have 10 minutes of timeout, with basic or manual scaling, you have 24H of timeout.](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#timeouts). Enough for your use case.